# PHP DataStructures find object by property

Tags: php, vector, data-structures, find

In PHP I need to find object index in collection (vector), How to find object with specific property ($object->name = "name: 3")?
Any suggestions ?

here is example:

```
<?php
//simple class
class tip {
    public $ID;
    public $name;
}

$col =  new \Ds\Vector();

//create few objects in $col
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $o = new tip();
    $o->ID = $i;
    $o->name = "name: $i";
    $col->push($o);
}

var_dump($col);

//search should return 4 (as 4 object in vector is object with name: "name: 4" but it returns false
var_dump($col->find("name: 3"));
?>
```

Comment: Where do you get the code for \Ds\Vector from?

Comment: @NigelRen I presume from here https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-vector.php

Comment: I also __doubt__ that this Vector class understands `name: 3` notation. As manual just says "Values will be compared by value and by type." So comparing strings and objects will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: You could basically just `foreach` your vector, and when you find the value you're looking for, you juste have to to `break`

Comment: Alone vector won't be enough without any tweaks to current code.

Comment: Not sure if this is an appropriate use of Vector to begin with. OP is basically using it as object storage, instead of a sequence of values. As such, most of Vector's methods seem irrelevant. Having `class tip extends Ds\Vector` might make more sense.

Comment: So it's not possible to have like Ds\Vector::filter  function ?

Comment: Hmm, Ds\Vector::filter in not giving copy of data but a reference to objects!!! I could use filter instead of find !!!

Comment: @MarkusAO you are right

Comment: You could probably use `filter` with a closure, like `function($o) use($q) { return $o->name === $q; }`, where `$q` is your criteria. You may need to reconsider the use of Vector here though. Vector is a sequence of values (and in that way, like a numerically indexed array). It doesn't have properties to operate on, it's also not an associative array, and I don't really see any benefit in using it here over standard core PHP structures. If this is a use case, not clear what your case is. If this is a learning exercise, you may want to design a case that takes actual advantage of Vector.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this with help of @MarkusAO, first this is wrong use of OP as @MarkusAO stated to use vector as storage device ...
Here is example:

```
$filter = $col->filter(function($value) {
    return $value->name == "name: 3";
});
//change name property of one object
if ($filter->count()==1) $filter[0]->name = "xxx";
//show filter object
var_dump($filter);
//show all objects
var_dump($col);
```